# Why are the slideshow pictures bigger than the screen (and container)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have solved all the problems before, thank you very much for help. But now new ones appeared. The thing is that when I deleted the size of all containers (it was 1024px before), my slide images became way bigger than the screen. See the images [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCCOu.png)[and][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPkol.png). 
 Please help cause I need slide images to be full sized on the home page without scrolling down.
HTML

```
<!--Start Home-->
<section class="home" id="home">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="mySlides">
            <img src="img/Home/вид1 классика.jpg" style="width:100%">
          </div>
          <div class="mySlides">
            <img src="img/Home/спальня море1.jpg" style="width:100%">
          </div>
          <div class="mySlides">
            <img src="img/Home/07.jpg" style="width:100%">
          </div>
          <div class="mySlides">
            <img src="img/Portfolio/4/розовая комната (5).jpg" style="width:100%">
          </div>
          <div class="mySlides">
            <img src="img/Portfolio/3/титова мал спальня (3).jpg" style="width:100%">
          </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!--End Home-->
```

CSS for the Home section

```
/*Home Section*/

.home {
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
.home .container {
    height: 850px;
}
.home .container .mySlides {
    padding-top: 70px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

CSS for the whole website (to see the characteristics of main elements)

```
html {
scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    max-width: 100%;
}
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container {
    margin: auto;
}
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.section-title {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.section-title h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.text-center {
    text-align: center!important;
}
.text-left {
    text-align: left!important;
}
.text-right {
    text-align: right!important;
}
```

JS

```
// Automatic Slideshow - change image every 5 seconds
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
  x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  setTimeout(carousel, 5000);    
}
```

It is written in the devtools that the section and the container has the height of 850 but the div with slides is way bigger. Don't know why. See [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anoqP.png)

Thank in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

the `mySlides` div has no `height` value so it takes the height of his content, and even if it did had a `height` you have an overflow problem. I suggest giving the img itself the `height` value or `max-height`.

Comment: Thank you. But if I write ".home .container .mySlides img {
    height: 870px;" the pictures become stretched.

Comment: this is why you only manipulate one dimension - or height or width. yot can try: `max-width: 100%; max-height: 870px;`. in the end, you need also images with the right dimensions.

Comment: Could you please tell about dimension? I am trying to play with images but nothing good happens. Either image is stretched or image is too heigh for the home page.